# disable scroll on bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to disable scroll on bootstrap column , here's my code

```
    <div class="container-fluid h-100">
      <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col-4 h-100 bg-dark fixed"></div>
        <div
          class="col-8 h-100"
        >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ut iste ullam qui laborum quibusdam ipsa quaerat, voluptatibus vitae laudantium similique nam nisi quasi. Perspiciatis repellendus quod vero aut at quam rerum non cum? Eius, consectetur officia alias nisi fuga facilis?</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I want to make the div which have the fixed class to stay on it's place and never scroll when i scroll the page down. I want only the div holding the text to scroll up and down and the other div stay on it's place as it is. how to achive that ?

Comment: add your css too

Comment: I'm only using bootstrap for styling

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable vertical scroll in bootstrap column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45206216/how-to-disable-vertical-scroll-in-bootstrap-column)

Comment: all classes I'm using are bootstrap classes

Comment: You will have to write custom css for this.
something like this :
.fixed { position:fixed; top:5%; left:2%; }